# Reference values: string or integer?

Tags: c#, database, strong-typing

We have reference values created from a Sequence in a database, which means that they are all integers. (It's not inconceivable - although massively unlikely - that they could change in the future to include letters, e.g. R12345.)

In our [C#] code, should these be typed as strings or integers?

Does the fact that it wouldn't make sense to perform any arithmetic on these values (e.g. adding them together) mean that they should be treated as string literals?  If not, and they should be typed as integers (/longs), then what is the underlying principle/reason behind this?

I've searched for an answer to this, but not managed to find anything, either on Google or StackOverflow, so your input is very much appreciated.

Comment: if you don't need to calculate with the values you can use strings without any problem. if you every think about calculating with the values you should use long (int) and avoid letters.

Comment: it's a choice. simple as that. A decision is what's needed. Remember KISS, YAGNI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of other differences:

**Leading Zeroes:**

Do you need to allow for these. If you have an ID string then it would be required

**Sorting:**

Sort order will vary between the types:

```
Integer:

1
2
3
10
100

String

1
10
100
2
3
```

So will you have a requirement to put the sequence in order (either way around)?

The same arguments apply to your typing as applied in the DB itself too, as the requirements there are likely to be the same. Ideally as Chris says, they should be consistent.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about sorting in the C# code, a custom comparator should easily sort strings as if they were integers, or vice versa.

Comment: **I would never in a million years store leading zeros in a database**  would you store money values with the currency symbol? or commas? `$12,345`.  do you store your dates with the slashes `12/25/2013` leading zeros are extra formatting for end users at display time.  They will force you to use long strings when a few byte numeric value would store the value better.  long strings make worse candidates for index and keys.  they waste more cache memory, especially on a primary key because primary keys are stored within every index.

Comment: @KM. You do if they're part of an ID string, which happens to be made up of numeric digits. Maybe a bank account number or something. Without the leading 0 it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JonEgerton, `You do if they're part of an ID string` what are you talking about?  00001234 = 1234 = 0000000000000001234.  why store a string '00001234` in 8 bytes when the number 1234 or any 8 digit number will easily fit into s 4 byte int?  if this a user displayed ID it is most likely searched on frequently (need index) and a good FK to related data. The 4 bytes values will and use half the memory cache, and have faster compares.

Comment: @KM: "00001234" != "0000000000000001234". These are not numerics, they are strings that happen to have characters that are numeric digits. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207231/sql-numeric-data-type-with-leading-zeros.

Comment: @JonEgerton, that is completely different that the OP's generated numeric sequences, yet shows what an big pain the leading zeros cause

Comment: In my particular case, leading zeros don't apply (the numbers are generated by an Oracle DB Sequence (.NEXTVAL) and are always integers.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few things to consider:

1. Are leading zeros important, i.e. is `010` different to `10`. If so, use `string`.
2. Is the sort order important?  i.e. should `200` be sorted before or after `30`?
3. Is the speed of sorting and/or equality checking important? If so, use `int`.
4. Are you at all limited in memory or disk space? If so, `int`s are 4 bytes, `string`s at minimum 1 byte per character.
5. Will `int` provide enough unique values?  A string can support potentially unlimited unique values.
6. Is there any sort of link in the system that isn't guaranteed reliable (networking, user input, etc)? If it's a text medium, int values are safer (all non-digit characters are erraneous), if it's binary, strings make for easier visual inspection (`R13_55` is clearly an error if your ids are just alphanumeric, but is `12372`?)

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of your description, these are values that currently happen to be represented by a series of digits; they are not actually numbers in themselves. This, incidentally, is just like my phone number: it is not a single number, it is a set of digits.

And, like my phone number, I would suggest storing it as a string. Leading zeros don't appear to be an issue here but considering you are *treating* them as strings, you may as well *store* them as such and give yourself the future flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

They should be typed as integers and the reason is simply this: retain the same type definition wherever possible to avoid overhead or unexpected side-effects of type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There are good reasons to not use use types like `int`, `string`, `long` all over your code. Among other problems, this allows for stupid errors like

- using a key for one table in a query pertaining another table
- doing arithmetic on a key and winding up with a nonsense result
- confusing an index or other integral quantity with a key

and communicates very little information: Given `int id`, what table does this refer to, what kind of entity does it signify? You need to encode this in parameter/variable/field/method names and the compiler won't help you with that.

Since it's likely those values will always be integers, using an integral type should be more efficient and put less load on the GC. But to prevent the aforementioned errors, you could use an (immutable, of course) `struct` containing a single field. It doesn't need to support anything but a constructor and a getter for the id, that's enough to solve the above problems except in the few pieces of code that need the actual value of the key (to build a query, for example).

That said, using a proper ORM also solves these problems, with less work on your side. They have their own share of downsides, but they're really not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to perform some mathematical calculations on the sequences, you can easily choose strings.

But think about sorting: Produced orders between integers and strings will differ, e.g. `1, 2, 10` for integers and `1, 10, 2` for strings.